# How to find equation of hyperbola given foci and a point?

Tags: conic-sections

I am currently studying multivariate calculus at university, and ive been given some practice problems before the first assignment.

The problem is:

> A hyperbola may be defined as the set of points in a plane, the
>   difference of whose distances from two fixed points $F_1$ and $F_2$ is a
>   constant. Let P be a point on the hyperbola. Suppose the foci of the
>   hyperbola are located at (0, ±c), and that $|P F_1| − |P F_2| = ±2a$. It
>   may be shown that the equation of the hyperbola is given by
>    $\frac{y^2}{a^2} - \frac{x^2}{b^2} = 1, where \space c^2 = a^2 + b^2$
>
> Hyperbolas have many useful applications, one of which is their use in
>   navigation systems to determine the location of a ship. Two
>   transmitting stations, with known positions transmit radio signals to
>   the ship. The difference in the reception times o
>
> f the signals is used to
>       compute the difference in distance between the ship and the two transmitting stations. This
>       infomation places the ship on a hyperbola whose foci are the transmitting stations.
>       Suppose that radio stations are located at Tanga and Dar es Salaam, two cities on the
>       north-south coastline of Tanzania. Dar-es Salaam is located 200 km due south of Tanga (you
>       may assume that Dar es Salaam is directly south of Tanga). Simultaneous radio signals are
>       transmitted from Tanga and Dar es Salaam to a ship in the Indian Ocean. The ship receives
>       the signal from Tanga 500 microseconds (µs) before it receives the signal from Dar es Salaam.
>       Assume that the speed of radio signals is 300m/µs.
>
> (a) By setting up an xy-coordinate system with Tanga having
>   coordinates (0, 100), determine the equation of the hyperbola on which
>   the ship lies.
>   (b) Given that the ship is due east of
>   Tanga, determine the coordinates of the ship.

If someone wouldnt mind giving me a few hints as to how I could solve this, I would be very grateful.

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown that the difference between the two distances (from ship to transmitting stations) is $2a$, where $a$ is the parameter appearing in the hyperbola equation. Let the distance between foci (that is between transmitting stations) be $2c$: you have then the relation $c^2=a^2+b^2$, whence you can compute $b$ and so determine the required equation. Of course you must also set the coordinate system so that Dar es Salaam has coordinates $(0,-100)$.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply, however I don't see how you compute b..? If you wouldn't mind explaining that it would be much appreciated. Thanks again, Tim

Comment: @Fishingfon $b^2=c^2-a^2$, where $a$ and $c$ are computed from the data as I explained.

Comment: Hey, Sorry  Imeant I was not sure how you computed a, not b. I don't see how you compute a when we don know the distance from ship to transmitting station. Thanks again, Tim :)

Comment: @Fishingfon Just think of the difference in the time signals are received, taking into account that signals travel at 300 m/µs.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the  clumsily handwritten note. Hope it addresses the point.

[image: HyperbolaObjectLocn]